# How can I delete a test case from TestRail

Tags: testrail

I use testrail just to write manual test cases. I dont use Test Runs/Milestones and other tabs. I only use "Test Cases" to add test cases. Sometimes I add some test cases by mistake (and later realize its a duplicate or not required for this feature etc..). How can I delete a test case? I only see the edit option but no delete option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestRail can be configured with various roles / user permissions that govern what the logged in user is allowed to do. This currently includes separate Add/Edit and Delete permissions for various entities (Attachments, Cases & Sections, Milestones, Suites etc.)

It's possible that your permissions do not allow you to delete test cases. You would need to contact your TestRail administrator to ensure you have the Delete "Cases & Sections" permission.

If you do have the correct permissions, test cases can be deleted in a few different ways:

1. In Test Case Edit mode, the right hand sidebar should have an Actions pane with a "Delete this test case" link
2. In the Suite view mode, hovering over a test case row should display a red circle that can be clicked to delete the case
3. In the Suite view mode, click the checkbox for a given test case row to select the test case, and then click the Delete button on the toolbar

Steps 2 and 3 should be immediately to the right of the Edit button / icon if you have the ability to delete test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename it to another one when you need a new test case and don't create the new one.